# Separating jQuery Mobile (1.1.0) from AMD (RequireJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, requirejs, amd

I'm trying to include jQuery Mobile in a project that uses RequireJS for AMD, however, I do not want to load jQuery Mobile in as an AMD module. The idea behind this is that we will be using AMD for application specific logic but any external library dependencies such as jQuery will be brought into global scope by just manually defining script tags.

The problem I'm having is defining a script tag for jQuery mobile before RequireJS script tag seems to cause RequireJS to define an anonymous module and create a conflict that I don't understand. I looked at both the jQuery and jQuery Mobile code and they are set up to conditionally call the `define()` method if it exists. Since I am including those tags before RequireJS loads, they should not be calling `define()`. I double checked this with breakpoints and they indeed do not.

When I include jQuery Mobile I get the following error:

```
Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object]
```

I don't understand how this is happening if jQuery Mobile isn't calling `define()`. What am I doing wrong here? Is this something with jQuery Mobile's new conditional AMD support?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To confirm, you should be using the built version of jQuery mobile, and you should include it before the require.js tag like so -- notice that jquery is included as a script tag since jQuery mobile depends on it:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/app"></script>
```

I expect that to work. The error you see may be generated if you have the scripts like this:

```
<script src="scripts/require.js" data-main="scripts/app"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
```

I consider this more of a problem with RequireJS, not jQuery mobile, something I want to fix for RequireJS 1.1. But the first set of script tags should work.

If that does not, it would be interesting to know more how your app's JS module uses jQuery and jQuery mobile.

Comment: So I did in fact have my scripts set up like your first example in my project and was still getting the error. I just discovered that the issue seems to arrive when both jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 and a separate library ([js-signals](http://millermedeiros.github.com/js-signals/)) is also included which also conditionally supports AMD. I checked and neither library is calling define and yet I still get the mismatch error. I put a quick POC together [here](https://github.com/jrolfs/RequireJS-External-Library-Test). I will continue to look into this, but I am quite new to AMD. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which browser are you testing on? I tried in Chrome and Safari and saw the error, but if I tried in Firefox it was fine. When I moved the script tags to the head instead of inside the body, the error went away in the webkit browsers. So I'm thinking it is some weird issue with webkit browsers and body content. So either place the scripts in the head or just load all the libs via requirejs (recommended)

Comment: That is weird. Sorry, I was testing in Safari and should have tested in some other browsers. I understand it is recommended to load all the libs with require but it just seems to make more sense to have more utility driven libraries like jQuery and Underscore on the global scope so the dependencies in AMD modules are just application modules and not libs but I may be misunderstanding something there. Just another minor reason I was setting things up this way is that a lot of libraries seem to be catching up to AMD right now and this avoids juggling one off AMD versions.

Comment: Anyways, I'm gonna go ahead and put those scripts in the head because I think that makes sense for this application. Thanks for the help and thanks for RequireJS!