# RequireJS does not work with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, requirejs

How should I include **jquery.mobile.js** in my project so that I can use it with RequireJS.

When I add jquery.mobile.js in my project I start getting following error.

> Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function ( $ ) {
>   factory( $, root, doc );
>   return $.mobile;
>   }

I also followed this post.
[Separating jQuery Mobile (1.1.0) from AMD (RequireJS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9522421/separating-jquery-mobile-1-1-0-from-amd-requirejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [working example](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette). It includes Requirejs, jQueryMobile, Backbone, and Marinonette.

In the [index.html](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette/blob/master/js/main.js) file, you need to specify the main module for requirejs to load.

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="js/main" src="js/libs/require-2.1.2.min.js"></script>
```

In this example, the main module is under ["js/main.js"](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette/blob/master/index.html)

Inside, main.js, you specify the require.config and use define to load your modules.